# Are public, in-class typedefs necessary in C++1y?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I've noticed `std::` containers tend to have `public`, in-class type aliases (`typedef`/`using`).
E.g., see Member Types at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector.

How are they useful? Aren't they just a relic of times when C++ didn't have things like `auto` and `decltype`?

When implementing a custom container, should it have such `typedef`s? What do I lose if I fail to provide them?

Comment: Please provide a concrete *example* where "things like `auto` and `decltype`" do the job, and where previously a public `typedef` had to be used.

Comment: I think those types are there so that the various type traits used by the algorithms in the algorithm header will not need to be instantiated explicitly   for each container type.

Comment: It also helps readability and maintainability to be explicit sometimes.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think a C++98 template depending on vector would have to do things like `std::vector<T>::iterator it = x.begin();` whereas in C++1y you don't have to know what the name of the returned type is: `auto it = x.begin();`.

Comment: @PSkocik: Well, for the iterator types you're right that the `typedef`s are not necessary for new code. But they need to be there in order to not break existing code.

Comment: It is easier to reason about code (e.g. convince an independent reviewer that it works as required) when there is explicit information about what type something actually is, and the typedefs do help some template-based code check if it has been correctly instantiated.   `auto` also, in some circumstances, deduces types that are different from what you would naturally expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a standard-library-compatible container, you do have to supply the typedefs.

If you look at the documentation, e.g. at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), you will see passages like this:

> std::vector meets the requirements of Container, AllocatorAwareContainer, SequenceContainer, ContiguousContainer (for T other than bool) (since C++17) and ReversibleContainer.

If you look up Container or SequenceContainer or any other thing listed there, you will find a list of requirements, and the typedefs (or rather types—they don't *have* to be typedefs, though they often are) are among them.

So if you are building a Container in the standard sense of the term, you need to provide the typedefs (and of course satisfy all other requirements too).

C++11 could in theory loosen the requirements, but it didn't. Perhaps because

```
std::vector<int>::iterator
```

is a heck of a lot more readable than

```
decltype(std::declval<std::vector<int>>().begin())
```

Or perhaps for some other reason.

Comment: I think the question is more about "do they serve a useful purpose" rather than "is there a formal requirement to have them". But yes at the end the question is *also* about formal requirements.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It is, but this helps too. Thanks, n.m. .

Comment: Upvoted for the readability observation, but note that this is just a matter of defining *the right support abstractions*. In C++03 the support abstractions were simple `typedef`s or type definitions. In C++11, for new code, they generally don't need to be: e.g. the types can be inferred by traits.

Comment: Just a question can we now replace `typedefs` rather with `using` alias declarations ? Is it compliant with Container concepts ?

Comment: @coincoin IMHO, yes. The concept mentions types, not how you get those types.

Answer (score 4):

They are extremly usefull when dealing with meta-programing, period.

let's catch a container by reference once if it's a container of POD, and another time when it's not:

```
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_pod<typename T::value_type>::value>
doSomething(T& container){
   //do something
}

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pod<typename T::value_type>::value>
doSomething(T& container){
   //do something
}
```

I'm doing a lot of C++ for Windows, and since Windows API provide C structs, I use many techniques like these to diffrentiate between real C++ objects and WinApi structs.

Answer (score 1):

typedef(s) allow to separate implementations from interfaces.

Take into acount that early the C++ does not define `auto` as it is defined now and `decltype` was absent in the Standard.

But even now when you have `auto` and `decltype` sometimes it is better to specify explicitly the type of an object. Otherwise the code can be difficult to read or it can lead to errors.

Consider a simple example with type specifier `auto`

```
unsigned int x = 0;
long y = 0;

auto p = new auto( x + y );
```

Can you say what is the type of the pointer p?

Is expression `*p` of unsigned type or signed type?

The answer depends on used platform. The type of p can be either `long *` or `unsigned long *`.

A similar problem exists for standard containers. So the Standard introduces general type names like `size_type` that guarantees that this type is unsigned type but its width can vary among platform.

Also this allows to write generic code.

In my profile there is a reference to my article where I show a problem that is related that standard class `std::bitset` does not have generic type `size_type`. In this case if you need to substitute for example class `std::vector<bool>` to `std::bitset` you need to change the code everywhere where there was used either `size_type` or some explicit type like `size_t`.